# rs:ClearSession=true has no effect if rc:Toolbar=true on Report Server

Tags: session, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

On SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a report which can be accessed using the following URL:

```
http://<myServer>/<myPath>:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true&rc:Toolbar=true&rc:Zoom=110&rc:Parameters=false&rc:Stylesheet=style.css&NoId=690567938&part=1000000
```

The problem is every time I access it, the same session will be used until it is expired, although I already set `rs:ClearSession` to true.

However, the following URL will generate a new session each time I access it (notice that `rc:Toolbar` is set to false here):

```
http://<myServer>/<myPath>:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:Zoom=110&rc:Parameters=false&rc:Stylesheet=style.css&NoId=690567938&part=1000000
```

I cannot find any information to indicate that `rs:Toolbar=true` and `rs:ClearSession=true` are mutually exclusive, so what might I've done wrong here?